# Fancybox iFrame content not showing

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using the iFrame function for the
first time to pull pages from a site I am developing, so these pages
are within the same domain.

You can see the same here: http://ee.rouviere.com/photo/portfolio if
you click on the first thumbnail image Architecture you will see that
the page loads but it is incomplete.

Most of the styling is stripped
out and the side row of thumbnails is missing. You can see the page
that it is pulling from here: http://ee.rouviere.com/photo_portfolio

The code I am using to launch the iFrame is:

```
$("a.view-preview2").fancybox({
       'frameWidth'    :       500,
       'frameHeight'   :       500,
       'hideOnContentClick': false
  });
```

I tried the iFrame example on fancybox.net and it works perfectly so I
am not sure what I am missing here. Any help will be greatly
appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Your links are dead.

Comment: what do you mean with "to build up those points" ? Fancybox is still used in old projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      $("a.image-preview").fancybox({
           'frameWidth'    :       500,
           'frameHeight'   :       500,
           'hideOnContentClick': false, 
           'type':'iframe'
      }); 
});
```

Have you tried adding `'type':'iframe'`

Comment: hi there. Yes, that made the difference. I had it in there before, but I realized that I needed to add the single quotes! 'iframe'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and `'type':'iframe'` did not solved it. I also had to add 
`'overlayShow':false`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      $("a.image-preview").fancybox({
           'frameWidth'    :       500,
           'frameHeight'   :       500,
           'hideOnContentClick': false,
           'overlayShow':false,
           'type':'iframe'
      }); 
});
```